# Route between two marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, google-directions-api

I am trying to develop an android application. That i am using `direction API` for draw a `route` between two `marker`. I am using the below code for drawing `route`. When i am running application first time it is working fine. but at second time the `direction api` shows `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`.

```
        GoogleDirection.withServerKey("AIzaSyCua7p46J7YKwxS99H5orm2Ikn8OltIcF0")
                .from(currentLatLng)
                .to(desLatLng)
                .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
                .execute(this);




@Override
public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success with status : " +direction.getStatus(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (direction.isOK()) {

        Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
        int legCount = route.getLegList().size();
        for (int index = 0; index < legCount; index++) {
            Leg leg = route.getLegList().get(index);
            //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(leg.getStartLocation().getCoordination()));
            if (index == legCount - 1) {
               // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(leg.getEndLocation().getCoordination()));
            }
            List<Step> stepList = leg.getStepList();
            ArrayList<PolylineOptions> polylineOptionList = DirectionConverter.createTransitPolyline(this, stepList,
                    5, Color.BLACK, 3, Color.BLUE);
            for (PolylineOptions polylineOption : polylineOptionList) {
                mMap.addPolyline(polylineOption);
            }
        }
        setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(route);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),direction.getStatus(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may see the "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" as a result of not having billing account , to use google direction api you will have to set billing account in your developer console.